# Best practice for table or table key names which clash with SQL syntax

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question or my title is a bit wrongly worded, but while creating my database for my assignment I see they want names like `Returns` and `Address` as a table name and table key name respectively.

It compiles no problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Returns 
(
..
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
..
Address varchar(30) NOT NULL,
..
)
```

but I see my MS SQL Server 2008 sp1 Syntax editor makes the words `Returns` and `Address` the same colour as the `CREATE TABLE` statement (blue),thus i guess these are keyords of the SQL language.

So is this a good naming convention or should I switch to something like:
`CustomerAddress` and `ProductReturns`?

Comment: Is the choice really that important?  In Python, people name variables `class_` or `klass` or `cls` instead of `class`, which is a keyword.

Comment: my only suggestion is keep the table names singular - not plural.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I'm not sure I come for am Java and C# based background and I was surprised to see it even compiled? SO is this question not really applicable? can I name tables and keys the same as keywords?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, yes you can. Some you won't be able to easily, `group`  and `date` comes to mind but there are _always_ other options.

Comment: @Randy Hmm is this pure choice or a convention? The only reason for my asking is I saw somewhere on the net naming tables plural or like `tblCustomer`?

Comment: Simple advice: avoid them, rename them ASAP. They can cause more pain in the future than renaming them now will. I tend to prefix suspect names with z (AFAIK, no keyword starts with 'z') To be pronounced with a German accent: `create table ztable (zdate DATE NOT NULL, ...);`

Comment: this is my personal preference.  when you read the values of the row, they refer to one of the objects not all of them, so you want to say something like Customer.name not Customers.name

Comment: @wildplasser hmm yes I see now they may become in conflict so I would rather rename them. may I ask what is the convention for table names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [Reserved Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for SQL-Server page at MSDN.

`RETURNS` is in the *Future Keywords* list which:

> The following keywords could be reserved in future releases of SQL Server as new features are implemented. Consider avoiding the use of these words as identifiers.

Comment: +1 thank you concrete evidence is what I needed so I guess its best avoided (will accept when I can)